# Documenting a lab environment

Tags: untagged

I've been tasked with setting up and managing a brand new lab environment, consisting of lots of machines in different roles. There's a VM host, several web servers, several database servers, and such.

There are very specific needs and processes that need to be documented as part of this lab environment, for instance we don't want automatic Windows updates turned on, and there is a lot of thought we want to capture to explain to multiple different parties (executives, managers, developers, IT managers, QA folks).

So as I'm doing the setup I really want to capture these conversations in some sort of formal document. I was just going to go ahead and create a Word .doc, organizing each server role with several discrete sections:

- Executive Summary
- Maintenance needs
- Inventory of installed software
- Hardware available
- Hardware defaults

What I'd like to know is if there are better templates I can follow when creating documentation for these machines. I'm hoping that whatever I end up creating is good enough to someone else rebuild the machines if needed.

Comment: Use a proper configuration management system. If you do this, not only will your server configurations be easily reproducible, but the configuration will also be self-documenting.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The most important things for a good documentation system are:

- Easy to update (or people wont update it, making it worse than useless)
- Easy to access - from any location, from multiple devices.
- Well organized - easy for people to find the information they need, and minimal duplication of the same information.

I tried word documents.  They fail at all 3 points.  Word documents are hard to update, you end up with people having different copies, etc.

The best system I have found for my usage is a wiki.  DokuWiki works quite well for my purposes.  I can access and update it easily from anywhere.

I have my wiki laid out with pages describing the whole network setup, which links to pages for each server, cluster and application.  This way all the details about a particular item are kept on seperate pages and can be linked to from every place that it is relevant - when something changes I only have to change it on one page, and I can easily find the information I am looking for.

It also allows you to specify namespace templates, so when I create a new server page, it is prepopulated with tables to enter IP addresses, hardware configuration, etc.  All the empty fields have FIXME written in them, so I can search the entire wiki for FIXME and see what is missing from the documentation.

If you really want to get fancy, you can write plugins that take things like config files, parse them, and display them in an easy to read format.  For example, I wrote a plugin called PatchPanel which takes a text description of a network patch panel and draws a picture of it with labels for where each port goes.

http://blog.emsley.ca/2014/04/documentation.html has a more complete writeup of how I have it setup (disclaimer: link to my blog, completely on topic though).